# Django Custom Group model

Tags: django, model

By default, in django the group model has the name as unique=True. Is it possible to remove this attribute and how? Does it have any major consequence?

Comment: Why do you want to remove it in the first place?

Comment: In my case an user belongs to one or more companies and each company may have their own groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably better to prefix the name of the group with something distinctive rather than try to make it non-unique. By default `Group.name` is used as a [natural key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/serialization/#natural-keys) by Django, for serialization purposes.

You could work around display issues by doing something during display, like:

```py
def get_group_name(group):
    if "|" in group.name:
        return group.name.split("|")[1]
    return group.name

group = Group.objects.create(name="COMPANY_X|Sales")
print(get_group_name(group))
# Sales
```

You can still define your own Group model but it would require [customizing your user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/) model quite significantly, which is a lot of work, and there may still be things that rely on Group name uniqueness in Django internals.